# QR Code breaks URL after #

Tags: javascript, angularjs, qr-code

I'm currently trying to let people download a file on their smartphone by scanning a QR Code that contains an URL to the download path.
The QR Code is generated by Googles Charts Api Url.

The problem is, the download path contains a # due to I'm working with Angular, and the QR code only contains the url part before the # .
Once I remove the # it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to encode the URL:

```
encodeURIComponent("http://yoursite.com/path/#thing")
```

Outputs:

```
"http%3A%2F%2Fyoursite.com%2Fpath%2F%23thing"
```

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/overview) say that the data must be URL-encoded.

Comment: Makes sense ;). Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried URL encoding? Replace # with %23 and see if it works.